# WebApi2 Status Code 500 {"message":"An error has occurred."} With no Detail

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, asp.net-web-api2

i facing an Error in my webApi App and I've searched a lot but nothing works for me.

my application works fine on my local computer and even it works fine with IIS on my local PC. but when I deploy it on the server ( debug and release mode tested) it just give me Internal Error 500 with just

> {"message":"An error has occurred."}

in response and no detail.

I tried almost everything. I turned off Custom Error mode I put this line in my Global.asax ( application _start method )

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

I really don't know how can I get the error detail.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried everything but just deleting the application pool and recreate that everything went right. I don't know what was the exact problem but it solved my problem